# why does GestureDetector doesn't working well?

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to set 'inputVoice()' after when i touch the screen double times. For example, when i excute app and then after i touch the screen double times, i want to do voice input. so i did like that,

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
inputVoice(); 
return super.onDoubleTap(e); }
```

but when i execute app, it doesn't working. It works nothing including GestureDectector and inputVoice. Here is the full code and xml. I don't know what is the wrong.

```
public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
TextToSpeech tts;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 5);

    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new Search()).commit();
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            tts.setLanguage( Locale.KOREAN);
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                tts.speak( "다음은 상품 상세 페이지입니다. 원하시는 상품을 이야기해주세요" , TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH , null );

            }
        }
    });

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, mOnSimpleOnGestureListener);
  //  inputVoice();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            int id = menuItem.getItemId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.navigation_item_drink:
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FirstItemFragment()).commit();
                    Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_item_meat:
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SecondItemFragment()).commit();
                    Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_item_dairy_product:
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ThirdItemFragment()).commit();
                    Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_item_processed_food:
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FourthItemFragment()).commit();
                    Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_item_vegetable:
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FifthItemFragment()).commit();
                    Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

            }

            return true;
        }
    });

}

public MenuItem searchItem;

public SearchView searchView;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);



    searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.onActionViewExpanded(); // 바로 검색창 활성화

    searchView.setQueryHint("검색");


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            InputMethodManager imm= (InputMethodManager) CategoryActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
            searchView.setQuery("", false);
            searchView.setIconified(true);

            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Search(s)).commit();
            Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, "search 결과 :" +s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // 여기에서는 터치 이벤트를 넘겨주어서 받고 난후, 리턴값을 돌려준다.
    // 일반 뷰에 붙여도 된다.
    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
private GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mOnSimpleOnGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "녹음시작", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        inputVoice();
        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onDoubleTapEvent(e);
    }

    @Override

    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e); }
};


public void inputVoice() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "ko-KR");
        final SpeechRecognizer stt = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        stt.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
                toast("음성 입력 시작...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {
                toast("음성 입력 종료");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) {
                toast("오류 발생 : " + error);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle results) {
                ArrayList<String> result = (ArrayList<String>) results.get(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Search(result.get(0))).commit();
                replyAnswer(result.get(0));
                stt.destroy();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

            }
        });
        stt.startListening(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        toast(e.toString());
    }
}

public void replyAnswer(String input){
    try{tts.speak( input + " 검색결과입니다." , TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH , null );


    } catch (Exception e) {
        toast(e.toString());
    }
}

private void toast(String msg){
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

And xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/notice_search_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

please help me anybody who can solve. Thanks.

Comment: try, for testing, to return `true` from `@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method

Comment: @pskink Do you mean change like return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); -> return true;  ? i tried it, but it does not working..

Comment: then add some `Log.d` inside `onTouchEvent` and post the logcat output when double tapping

Comment: @pskink Umm, i don't know well about how to add some Log.d and post the logcat output. Could you explain more specific? I'm really want to solve by myself, but it's really hard to do..